# Trying to get FileAppender to Append to a file, not truncate and overwrite

Tags: log4cplus

OK, got log4cplus to log stuff to a file.  Now I want it to simply append when the program re-starts instead of overwrite.

I tried this:
`log4cplus::SharedAppenderPtr myAppender(new log4cplus::FileAppender "myLogFile.log",std::ios_base::ate));`

but it still truncated and overwrote.

I don't want to use the Rolling or Daily FileAppenders (yet at least).

Thanks,
-g

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass down `std::ios::app` instead. That is what the code checks for.